# How can I pass a parameter to a Doctrine2 custom function in the Query Builder select() method?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, query-builder

In my Symfony2 project I am retrieving an ordered set of entity IDs from an Elasticsearch index. I'm then passing this list to Doctrine2 to retrieve the actual entities, by way of a `WHERE IN()` call.

This doesn't return them in the correct order, so I think I need to use the MySQL-specific `FIELD()` function. I've created a custom DQL function to allow the functionality.

So now I'm using the following code to build a Doctrine query object, but the parameters aren't being parsed into the `select()` method:

```
$itemIds = array(4,8,2,1);

$this->getRepository()
    ->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('i, FIELD(i.id, :ids_string) AS HIDDEN fixed_order')
        ->where('i.id IN (:ids)')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'ids_string' => implode(',', $itemIds),
            'ids' => $itemIds))
        ->orderBy('fixed_order', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
;
```

This fails with the error `"Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"`, so apparently it's not "seeing" the `:ids_string` in the `select()` method.

I initially tried putting the `FIELD()` function in the `orderBy()` call, but it doesn't look like this is getting parsed for custom DQL function calls, and I imagine I'd run into the same problem as above.

**EDIT 1** I'm aware I could put the base data directly into the `select()` call.

**EDIT 2** I've given up and put the bare data into the `select()` call (which I wanted to avoid). This worked, but then it became necessary to implement Koc's suggestion of using the  `HIDDEN` keyword to prevent Doctrine returning `array(Object i, array(fixed_order))` instead of just `Object i`

Answer (score 0):

From Doctrine 2.2 you can use `HIDDEN` keyword for avability field in order by without hydration them.

Try:

```
->select('i, FIELD(i.id, :ids_string) AS HIDDEN fixed_order')
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't appear to have any relation to the question asked. Please could you explain what you mean?

Comment: I've figured out what you mean now, thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my question to give context for why you suggested this.

Comment: If you want to highlight your code, you just need to put 4 spaces in front of it, no need to add ` :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to kick yourself when you notice the problem...

Try re-reading your sentence: "so apparently it's not "seeing" the **:ids_string** in the select() method".

And then take a close look at your code: **'id_string'** => implode(',', $itemIds)

Comment: I was all ready to kick myself, but unfortunately that's just a typo in the question (which I will now fix). I still get the same error (which I will also add to the question). Thanks for spotting that though...